# Rosserial Arduino with Groovy

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I am new to ROS
Running Groovy on 12.04 LTS.

i am trying to add the Rosserial for the Communication of Arduino with ROS.
every thing goes fine i follow this tutorial wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup.

1.i installed Arduino IDE

2.i run all these commands successfully

cd catkin_workspace/src

git clone //github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial.git

cd catkin_workspace

catkin_make

catkin_make install

source catkin_workspace/install/setup.bash

Al last when i run this Command after going into the libraries folder of sketchbook.

rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py

**i get this Message**]

[rospack] Error: stack/package rosserial_arduino not found

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79551/rosserial-arduino-with-groovy/) by [Neo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2306/neo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You forgot the the dot on the last command `rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .` Try that. Also, your source should be source `PATH_TO/catkin_workspace/install/setup.bash` if in your home directory, `source ~/catkin_workspace/install/setup.bash`.  Can you `roscd` into rosserial_arduino?

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2306/neo/) on 2013-09-24**:
thnaks i am now able to compile code with ros.h in arduino IDE